# Error Insight does not work in C++Builder 11.3

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

I upgraded from C++Builder Community Edition 10.4 to 11.3.

Error Insight no longer works. It used to display a red ball in the gutter wherever there was an error. It no longer does this in 11.3. It does increase the error count in the bottom editor bar when I introduce an error, but there is no indication of where the errors are in the source code.

Did I miss a setting or something?  Can I turn this behavior back on?

Answer (score 0):

I, too, made that same "upgrade" recently. When I did the following changes it seemed to at least underline the error.

Tools->User Interface->Language->Error Insight

Show Error Insight Levels: Everything
Editor rendering style: Smooth Wave
Uncheck Show Error Insight in Editor Gutter
Inactive Code Opacity Precent: 30

Not really sure which of these settings changed it for me, I was just taking stabs in the dark, but it's working for me now!